# Tomcat and SLF4J - not writing log to file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, slf4j

I am trying to implement a logging trail for my app using slf4j-log4j12. I've configured everything and it worked fine while i was testing it in standalone mode. Now that i had deployed it in tomcat, it stopped working! It simply prints the log (even the one i create with slf4j) in the console, but not in the file!

Here is my log4j.xml:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <param name="File" value="assp.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And here is my testing class

```
private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);
@RequestMapping("*")
public String root(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    LOGGER.info("{} - entering root page. Redirecting to index.", System.currentTimeMillis());
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Output (in console):

```
INFO 1404999952210 - entering root page. Redirecting to index.
```

Can someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Check the location/permission of the log file. Maybe you haven't added write permissions to allow tomcat to modify it.

Comment: and give the log file in absolute path, so you know where it must be written.

Comment: I gave the absolute path and no luck although it is working in standalone...

Comment: Check the Tomcat log level.   If you have access, bump the Tomcat log level up to ALL, restart the server and check the Tomcat log output for errors when it attempts to start your application logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i solve the problem. I follow the apache documentation [Here - Using LOG4J](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j)

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem i had.